# Waterfall Node.js of Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am writing async.waterfall in my biz. See code below. When I run the code, I got 'Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined', I do think I pass the right param.

```
 function checkDeleteStatus(id) {
  const idType = id instanceof Array;
  const whereparam = idType ?  [[id]] : [id];
  let sql = `select status from ${bookingSheet} where id ${idType ? 'in' : '=' } ?`;
  func.connPool(sql, whereparam, (err,rows,fields) => {
    if(err == null){    
      let passTag = true;     
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {  
        let row = rows[i];
        if (row.status == 0) {
          passTag = false;
          break;
        }
      }     
      return (callback)=>{
        passTag ? callback(null, id) : callback('No', null);
      }
    } else {   
      return (callback)=>{
        callback(err, null);
      }    
    }
  });
}

function deleteBooking(data, callback) {
  let sql = `delete sql`;
  func.connPool(sql, [data], (err,rows,fields) => {
    if(err==null){
      callback(null, data)
    } else {   
      callback(err, null)
    }
  });
}

......
async.waterfall([checkDeleteStatus(id), deleteBooking], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    res.json({ code: 400, message: err.toString() })
  } else {
    res.json({ code: 200, message: "Query Successfully", data: result })
  }
})
```

Interesting thing is, when I try to write below for checkDeleteStatus, it will run correctly. Is that mean, return part goes before sql part? I am new for using node.js waterfall, sorry for this kind of dumb question.

```
 function checkDeleteStatus(id) {
  const idType = id instanceof Array;
  const whereparam = idType ?  [[id]] : [id];
  let sql = `select status from ${bookingSheet} `;

      return (callback)=>{
        callback(null, id);
      }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the resone, the function should write like below. return (callback)=> should expend its range.

```
 function checkDeleteStatus(id) {
      return (callback)=>{
  const idType = id instanceof Array;
  const whereparam = idType ?  [[id]] : [id];
  let sql = `select status from ${bookingSheet} where id ${idType ? 'in' : '=' } ?`;
  func.connPool(sql, whereparam, (err,rows,fields) => {
    if(err == null){    
      let passTag = true;     
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {  
        let row = rows[i];
        if (row.status == 0) {
          passTag = false;
          break;
        }
      }     
        passTag ? callback(null, id) : callback('No', null);

    } else {   
        callback(err, null);

    }
  });}
}
```